# Suppress new buffer when running typeset command (C-c C-c) in AUCTeX

Tags: buffers, auctex

When running `C-c C-c` to typeset/compile the LaTeX code in the current buffer, a second buffer pops up to show the compilation -- is there a way to suppress this buffer if there are no errors?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043004/emacs-compile-buffer-auto-close) help?

Comment: This isn't the default behavior.  Did you set [`TeX-show-compilation`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Processor-Options.html#index-TeX_002dshow_002dcompilation) to t?